# Disable Contact Creation from custom group in Odoo12cr

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

I use Odoo 12 cr and I have create a custom group which has access to read certain models, but when I create a new user and assign it to the group technician, it can by default create contacts and I want to revoke this permission from the group.

the group is:

```
<record id="group_technical" model="res.group">
  <field name="name">Technician</field>
</record>
```

I already know that disabling "Contact Creation" revoke it, but is there a way to disable it from the group?

Answer (score 0):

you will be creating `ir.model.access.csv` file which would be added to the `__manifest__.py` file. it must be loaded after the group definition file.

```py
[
    'data': [
        'security/security.xml',         # group definition file
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',  # model access file
]
```

the group definition file would be:

```xml
<record id="group_technical" model="res.group">
  <field name="name">Technician</field>
</record>
```

the `ir.model.access.csv` file would be:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_res_partner_technician,res.partner.technician,model_res_partner,group_technical,1,0,0,0
```